# Can I get the time when an asp.net page was compiled?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible, within an asp.net page, to the get time at which point that page was last compiled?

I would like to distinguish between when a page has been delivered, and when that page has been updated, compiled, and then delivered (typically there's a slight delay, but a compile timestamp would make things a bit more concrete).

Ideally a simple solution exists, it's not particularly critical but a bit frustrating when during development we end up refreshing a page x times before the recompiled version appears.

cheers :)

Comment: Why not precompile the web site so you don't have to worry about the compilation process slowing the page down?

Comment: This is for during development.. we make a change, then it can be up to 30 seconds before the page is compiled. So we refresh the page and test - only to find we're still using the old version. If we could just refresh and see if the time of compilation had changed, we'd know we're using the updated version?

Comment: I'm almost sure that this cannot be done, but not 100% sure.

Comment: 30 secs for compiling a page... And I just got another reason for hating web-forms.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/determining-build-date-the-hard-way.html

Comment: @rsenna, I think it's actually to do with the distributed filesystem I'm using (though not maintaining.. it's just what I have..). Locally the compilation is quick. Thanks for the other responses too guys :)

Comment: @TablooQuijico That explains a lot, but if you were using ASP.NET MVC you would have much less C# code associated to the pages... And hence lower compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it's likely that this is not possible. I want to close the question but also feel it's useful in case someone searches for similar to know it's already been asked.